# Using table valued params with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, table-valued-parameters

Is there a way to use SQL Server table-valued parameters in Entity Framework in a way that doesn't require you to use a stored procedure or string-based queries like `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("")` ?

Something similar to Dapper where I can pass a `DataTable` and specify the user-defined type name to use. Probably must be some sort of overload of `IEnumerable<>.Contains()` or `.Join()` so that I can build a join in a generated query.

The goal is to stay with expression trees and don't mess with strings.

Comment: Not as far as I am aware, although you may be able to write some sort of extension to EF to do this

Comment: You can use Dapper and EF together.